Python pandas, can't use mean() method with grouby
I'm currently learning pandas and I've encountered an error. the database I used: https://github.com/KeithGalli/pandas/blob/master/pokemon_data.csv
I've tried, as per youtube tutorial:
print(df.groupby(['Type 1']).mean())

but it return error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1942, in _agg_py_fallback
    res_values = self._grouper.agg_series(ser, alt, preserve_dtype=True)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 864, in agg_series
    result = self._aggregate_series_pure_python(obj, func)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 885, in _aggregate_series_pure_python
    res = func(group)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2454, in <lambda>
    alt=lambda x: Series(x, copy=False).mean(numeric_only=numeric_only),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 6549, in mean
    return NDFrame.mean(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 12420, in mean
    return self._stat_function(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 12377, in _stat_function
    return self._reduce(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 6457, in _reduce
    return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 147, in f
    result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 404, in new_func
    result = func(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, mask=mask, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 720, in nanmean
    the_sum = _ensure_numeric(the_sum)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1701, in _ensure_numeric
    raise TypeError(f"Could not convert string '{x}' to numeric")
TypeError: Could not convert string 'CaterpieMetapodButterfreeWeedleKakunaBeedrillBeedrillMega BeedrillParasParasectVenonatVenomothScytherPinsirPinsirMega PinsirLedybaLedianSpinarakAriadosYanmaPinecoForretressScizorScizorMega ScizorShuckleHeracrossHeracrossMega HeracrossWurmpleSilcoonBeautiflyCascoonDustoxSurskitMasquerainNincadaNinjaskShedinjaVolbeatIllumiseKricketotKricketuneBurmyWormadamPlant CloakWormadamSandy CloakWormadamTrash CloakMothimCombeeVespiquenYanmegaSewaddleSwadloonLeavannyVenipedeWhirlipedeScolipedeDwebbleCrustleKarrablastEscavalierJoltikGalvantulaShelmetAccelgorDurantLarvestaVolcaronaGenesectScatterbugSpewpaVivillon' to numeric

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\advanced.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(df.groupby(['Type 1']).mean())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2452, in mean
    result = self._cython_agg_general(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1998, in _cython_agg_general
    new_mgr = data.grouped_reduce(array_func)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1469, in grouped_reduce
    applied = sb.apply(func)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 393, in apply
    result = func(self.values, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1995, in array_func
    result = self._agg_py_fallback(how, values, ndim=data.ndim, alt=alt)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1946, in _agg_py_fallback
    raise type(err)(msg) from err
TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]

Since it's an issue with string values (it worked for the guy in tutorial), I've tried this:
    print(df[['HP','Attack','Defense']].groupby(['Type 1']).mean())

but it returned another error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\advanced.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(df[['HP','Attack','Defense']].groupby(['Type 1']).mean())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 9183, in groupby
    return DataFrameGroupBy(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1329, in __init__
    grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\pandastutorial\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 1043, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'Type 1'

What worked is this:
    print(df.groupby(['Type 1']).agg({'Speed':'mean', 'Defense':'mean'}))


but I need the mean from all numeric values and I don't want to specify it individually. I know it can be useful when you have specify mean for one column and, for example, min for another, but it gets annoying and sometimes impossible for huge databases. Is there a way to do it more quickly? Cheers

This is something that changed in Pandas 2.0. Columns which don't contain numbers are no longer ignored by default. Have you tried .groupby(...).mean(numeric_only=True)? See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html

Thanks! it's solved. If u'd like to add it as answer I'd mark it as proper one. Thanks a lot
